# XML auto generation issue

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

This is what my xsd looks like. Air and Car extend Segment.

```
<xs:element name="PNR" type="PNR" />

<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Segments" >
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Segment" type="Segment"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="Air">
 <xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="Segment">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Departure" type="AirportInfo" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Arrival" type="AirportInfo" />

    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
 </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Car">
 <xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="Segment">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="PickUp" type="AddressInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="DropOff" type="AddressInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>

    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
 </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I want an output that looks like this:

```
<Segments>
 <Segment xsi:type="Air">
  <Departure></Departure>
  <Arrival></Arrival>
 </Segment>
 <Segment xsi:type="Car">
  <PickUp></PickUp>
  <DropOff></DropOff>
 </Segment>
</Segments>
```

But when I auto-generate XML from my XSD using a tool such as xmlspy or a .net library (or whatever), I get this (Air generated multi times w/o Car).

```
<Segments>
 <Segment xsi:type="Air">
  <Departure></Departure>
  <Arrival></Arrival>
 </Segment>
 <Segment xsi:type="Air">
  <Departure></Departure>
  <Arrival></Arrival>
 </Segment>
</Segments>
```

Is there something wrong with my XSD?

Comment: Why would it generate the XML you want? It generated valid XML based on your schema. Your schema doesn't prevent two "Air" elements.

Comment: I don't mind if it generates two "Air"...I need it to generate "Car" as well...How do i do that?

Comment: Why are you doing auto-generation? What's the purpose? Auto-generation is only meant for generating sample documents.

Comment: I have a jQuery plugin (a UI plugin) that will take the input of XML and display in tree view. I have several XSDs. I want to populate the tree view based on users' selection of the XSD. so I take the XSD, generate the XML and bind. The XSD is subject to change so I don't want to use static XML if I can avoid.

Comment: Right, but why do you want one set of XML generated vs. another? It seems like you'd be better off populating the tree view from the schema, not from the instance document.

Comment: the treeview control doesn't take XSD, only XML

Comment: XSD _is_ XML; you know that, right? I don't see anything in XMLspy to tell it to try to generate all subtypes of an abstract type.

Comment: well i just tried giving the treeview control xsd, it broke. it doesn't take meta-xml. @John, thanks for looking in xmlspy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a technique I once used to generate XML from a set of schemas. Although it doesn't look like the right class for the job, take a look at the [XmlSchemaValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidator.aspx) class. The trick is that you can ask it what is valid for the document you're validating at that point in the validation. You can then *generate* the XML that is valid at that point in the document, and *validate* the same XML, in order to update the XmlSchemaValidator. You can then ask it again what is valid at that point in the document, etc.

When you get to an abstract type, you'll have to know to generate one of each possible derived type.

Comment: Thx for the advice. I'll play w/ it. but it seems to me that what i'm trying to achieve should be a common thing, and the .net library is missing some native functionality that should fulfill it.

Comment: If it's missing functionality, then it's been missing for a decade, and XMLspy is missing the same functionality. You may be mistaken about how common this is. How frequently does your schema change? How much time would it take to modify the XML by hand when the schema changes?